# KQL / Kusto: Can I consolidate the "remaining" columns into one catchall column?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, data-ingestion

I have input with a known set of columns (say **A-C**) and a variable number of additional columns. I would like to ingest this into a table with columns **A-C** plus a column **theRest**. So from the input **A** goes into **A**, **B** into **B** etc, and if **D** exists in a record it would go to **theRest** as **"D":"valueofD"**. For  another record containing **X** and **Y** it would become **A, B, C, theRest=["X":"valueofX", "Y":"valueofY"]**

I'm trying something along the lines of

```
T | project A, B, C, theRest = bag_remove_keys(pack_all(), dynamic(["A","B","C"]))
```

which basically does what I want, except that (ofcourse) my case is a bit more complex and instead of handcoding `dynamic(["A","B","C","D","E"]`, I would like to create something for `dynamic(<expression>)` where `<expression>` is the array of column names in the tabular expression `T`. The expression `T` has a varying number of columns, so the columns to remove by `bag_remove_keys()` vary also.

**Edit after first answer from @David:**

My example was maybe too simple.
Here is my code which almost does what I want, except the formatting of **theRest**.

```
let T= datatable (data: dynamic)
[
dynamic([{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3}]),
dynamic([{"X":4,"A":1,"B":5,"C":3,"Y":2}]),
dynamic([{"A":3,"G":7,"B":2,"C":1}]),
];
let X = datatable(A:int, B:int, C:int, data:dynamic) [];
let T_base_cols = toscalar(X | getschema | summarize make_list(ColumnName));
T | mv-expand Results = data
   | project  A=toint(Results['A']),
              B=toint(Results['B']),
              C=toint(Results['C']),
              theRest = bag_remove_keys(pack_all(), T_base_cols)
```

This gives output like this

```
A   B   C   theRest
1   2   3   {"Results":{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3}}
1   5   3   {"Results":{"X":4,"A":1,"B":5,"C":3,"Y":2}}
3   2   1   {"Results":{"A":3,"G":7,"B":2,"C":1}}
```

and I am expecting

```
A   B   C   theRest
1   2   3   
1   5   3   {"X":4,"Y":2}
3   2   1   {"G":7}
```

or similar format without curly braces in the last column.

**Edit2:**

After the excellent second answer from @David I came up with this

```
let T= datatable (data: dynamic)
[
dynamic([{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3}]),
dynamic([{"X":4,"A":1,"B":5,"C":3,"Y":2}]),
dynamic([{"A":3,"G":7,"B":2,"C":1}]),
];
let T_base_cols = dynamic(["data","$.Results.A",'$.Results.B','$.Results.C']);
//print T_base_cols
T | mv-expand Results = data
   | project  A=toint(Results['A']),
              B=toint(Results['B']),
              C=toint(Results['C']),
              theRest=trim('{"Results":|}$',tostring( bag_remove_keys(pack_all(),T_base_cols)))
```

which yields

```
1   2   3   {}
1   5   3   {"X":4,"Y":2}
3   2   1   {"G":7}
```

I will do some testing to find out if there is any performance implications of either solution (I need to ingest and transfrom about 160TB of data into Azure Data Explorer :-))

I am very happy with this forum!

Comment: Are you sure your source data (T) is built of arrays?

Comment: Are you sure your source data (T) is built of arrays (it does not change much, just requires an additional mv-expand operation)?

Comment: Yes, the data is in arrays (multiple json records in one row), so I have to flatten it with `mv-expand`. (I see what you mean, BTW - I have a single item in my arrays - I thought it would be better readable than `dynamic([{<record1>},{<record2>},{<record3>}])` for the input

Answer (score 1):

Here is a completely dynamic solution.

I have changed the tables names to *source* and *target* so it will be easier to understand what is going on in the context of update policy.

```
let source = datatable (data: dynamic)
[
    dynamic([{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3}])
   ,dynamic([{"X":4,"A":1,"B":5,"C":3,"Y":2}])
   ,dynamic([{"A":3,"G":7,"B":2,"C":1}])
];
let target = datatable(A:int, B:int, C:int, data:dynamic)[];
let target_fixed_cols = toscalar
(
    target 
    | getschema 
    | summarize make_list_if(ColumnName, ColumnName != "data")
);
source
| mv-expand data
| extend target_rest_keys = set_difference(bag_keys(data), target_fixed_cols)
| extend target_fixed_bag = bag_remove_keys(data, target_rest_keys)
| evaluate bag_unpack(target_fixed_bag)
| extend theRest = bag_remove_keys(data, target_fixed_cols)
| extend theRest = iff(array_length(bag_keys(theRest)) == 0, dynamic(null), theRest)
| project-away data, target_rest_keys
```

| A | B | C | theRest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |  |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | {"X":4,"Y":2} |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | {"G":7} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4VSTU%20DQBC9k/Af1j1Bsk2sHzHBcGh78ObBk6YxZLpMW%20wuNMtSi9b/7rAgbW2NcNj5ePPmvQWFlpVFZSSymKVg6Z0pZEETRiytc9CZDH1v6nuMnq4QTD/5iEdDwcc8uhJ8wqPrr9fQYcQB5plHN2KPvG2Rgr/Q1Dn8yHUfeHR3wDx0yNd731Mk1oJZ0HEgNhhFWW4FG7fHpD2cgR/90%20PpZJ5tMU1koUoiskUpQYHxvaA12a1okx2juJRL1NBXykprMNkHMg0rTFRW2iSbB5NCVTp/BI2koo/ZRcx4o4aTi5B0tNftezumNwPcriFPndqmgluLlHYyDRLxCutGZUl5ms3naDCXGMxg4TruQ4Xi1Fh4Stc2aZLomnmDutjgnkac7G1JNqAqsOhmqnwNchX8ZjzatsQnIvhvyR9S%202HyGoAxUCcK84Vd7i13mDBkccwuRf9T5pVSzVV07YZ1bYo3lHYA71Cz8x6/Af5qktACAwAA)

Answer (score 1):

If the target table columns (A, B & C) are known in advance, it becomes quite straightforward.
The last line is for replacing an empty bag (`{}`) with a dynamic null.

```
let source = datatable (data: dynamic)
[
    dynamic([{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3}])
   ,dynamic([{"X":4,"A":1,"B":5,"C":3,"Y":2}])
   ,dynamic([{"A":3,"G":7,"B":2,"C":1}])
];
let target = datatable(A:int, B:int, C:int, data:dynamic)[];
let target_fixed_keys = dynamic(["A", "B", "C"]);
source
| mv-expand data
| project A = data.A
         ,B = data.B
         ,C = data.C
         ,theRest = bag_remove_keys(data, target_fixed_keys)
| extend theRest = iff(array_length(bag_keys(theRest)) == 0, dynamic(null), theRest)
```

| A | B | C | theRest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |  |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | {"X":4,"Y":2} |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | {"G":7} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA21RTWuEMBC9C/6HIScDaen2g0KKB/XQe08tIpLV0bWNusTsorT9703i2rVsE8iElzdv3kwkahj6gyoQQiiFNnsrEQJ75VBOnWibgvpe6ntg1gkI0k8SEb5hJCb8lpGE8LvvjDoOW3FeCb9nZ+bDzGTkzWT9x4/c6zPhjyvljWNmT74njVktVG3CymwQ8abTDOI5JHNwDSz+07/ZedWMWOYfOA1WaKlvyjMwdc2RkIyalHkyvvcF7fEKx73oSidskb3q37HQEJ28XEfziNxi8YLGazRZ0GSN6h2+4GB72oo6V9j2R3Tm3C+wS9PU1sdRo7FzTm6qKhBKiSmX2NV6F1g1J3PiUAphCDfst+PuICVliwT9AVrTBP8MAgAA)